# how to dynamicly make <style> tag to work or not as needed

Tags: javascript, css

I have an question about modify the  tag type attribute problem. In my case, I want to dynamicly change the type to make it work or disabled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style r = "1" type = "text/css">
    h1 {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  <style r = "2" type = "not work">
    h1 {
      font-size: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var style1 = document.querySelector('[r="1"]')
      var style2 = document.querySelector('[r="2"]')
    </script>
    <h1>this text can be either 20px or 40px</h1>
    <input type="button" value="make text 20px" onclick = "style1.type='text/css';style2.type='not work'">
    <input type="button" value="make text 40px" onclick = "style2.type='text/css';style1.type='not work'">
</body>
</html>
```

So here's the example : [click me](https://jsfiddle.net/FatShen3/kn2v7cck/1/)

It works on chrome, but nor work in ie11, safari. Anybody can help ? Thanks a lot.

Addition: What i am doing is to change page style depends on some condition, say: language. In some reason I cant use mvvm framework.

Comment: U want to disable an input by clicking a button? Or disable a css class?

Comment: @Firefly No, I just want to change the <h1> font-size in the way by changing <style> tag

Comment: You want the [`disabled` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement#Properties)  https://jsfiddle.net/FatShen3/kn2v7cck/2 Also don't use invalid custom-attributes like that, `<style>` can have `class` or `id` attributes too.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you! that's what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you do it, actually. It's bad practice to change styles this way. It's better to change just one element style and not whole page style

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style type = "text/css">
    h1 {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    function changeStyle(fontSize) {
        var heading = document.querySelector('h1')
        heading.style.fontSize = fontSize;
    }
    </script>
    <h1>this text can be either 20px or 40px</h1>
    <input type="button" value="make text 20px" onclick = "changeStyle('20px')">
    <input type="button" value="make text 40px" onclick = "changeStyle('40px')">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What i am doing is to change page style depends on some condition, say: language. In some reason I cant use mvvm framework